# Python pass by value with nested lists?

Tags: python

I'm having a simple issue that's frustrating me. I'm sure I'm making a very obvious mistake, but I can't seem to find it. I want `l_old` to be the copy of `l` before undergoing iteration.  I have the following Python script.

```
import random
def runtest(n,steps):
    l=[]
    for i in range(n):
        sublist=[]
        for j in range(n):
            sublist.append(0)
        l.append(sublist)


    for k in range(n-1):
        i = random.randint(0,n-1)
        j = random.randint(0,n-1)
        while(l[i][j]==1):
            i = random.randint(0,n-1)
            j = random.randint(0,n-1)
        l[i][j]=1
    l_old = list(l)
    print("L_OLD BEFORE ITERATION", l_old)
    for k in range(steps):
        for i in range(n):
            for j in range(n):
                num = 0
                if i is not 0:
                    num+=l[i-1][j]
                if i is not n-1:
                    num+=l[i+1][j]
                if j is not 0:
                    num+=l[i][j-1]
                if j is not n-1:
                    num+=l[i][j+1]
                if(num > 1):
                    l[i][j]=1
    print("L_OLD AFTER ITERATION",l_old)
    return sum([sum(item) for item in l]), l_old, l
```

However, my output will look like this:

```
BEFORE ITERATION [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
AFTER ITERATION: [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 0, 0]]
```

So it's changing even though I made a copy of `l`'s value rather than the reference to `l`. I tried `l[:]` with the same results. What am I missing? I think it has to do with the fact that it's a nested list, but how can I write it such that all nested lists are copied by value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I think it has to do with the fact that it's a nested list,

Yes.  You've done a shallow copy:

```
l_old = list(l)
```

Slicing with `l[:]` is also a shallow copy.

> but how can I write it such that all nested lists are copied by value?

Try a deep copy:

```
from copy import deepcopy
l_old = deepcopy(l)
```